# Safari's auto margin + translate3d 1px bleed issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I am working w/a slideshow that works similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/trbwxyso/

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        body { background: #000; }
        #wrapper { margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; }
        #project_ctr { position: relative; width: 1500px; height: 576px; display: block; background: #000; overflow: hidden; }
        .project { position: absolute; width: 500px; height: 576px; display: block; }
        .ease { transition: 750ms ease all; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="project_ctr">
            <div class="project" style="background: #f00; left: 0;">
            </div>
            <div class="project" style="background: #fff; left: 500px;">
            </div>
            <div class="project" style="background: #00f; left: 1000px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.project').addClass('ease').css({
                    'transform': 'translate3d(-500px, 0, 0)'
                });
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.project').addClass('ease').css({
                        'transform': 'translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0)'
                    });
                }, 2000);
            }, 2000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Safari (on OS X) if you resize your browser you will see a 1px shift and bleed of the previous background.  I have tried every css trick to no avail. It appears to be a Safari only bug that's replicable and I can confirm it has been happening for at least two years.

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentColor` to the rescue. I'm aware of how ugly this Safari-only CSS is:

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) 
{ @media {
    .project:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: -1px;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 1px;
      z-index: 999;
      background: currentColor;
    }
  }
}
```

Here, the value `currentColor` set on background assumes whatever the current slide color is, making the fix scale pretty well.

https://jsfiddle.net/dgt4uqc4/2/

Comment: looks like the left side worked, thank you! I did however notice the project / slideshow width is now one pixel smaller and was showing a blue color on the right side.  I covered the 1px using your method (swapping left: -1px with right -1px and also added a border-right: 1px)  I've filed a bug with Apple.  Hope this can get fixed

Comment: You might want to try using `:after { }` for covering the other side.